# why use the self (reference?) in a "variable"?

Tags: python, self

I started studying / writing Twisted network programming and I came across with the following code:

```
def handle_REGISTER(self, name):
     if name in self.factory.users:
        self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
        return
     self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
     self.broadcastMessage("%s has joined the channel." % (name,))
     self.name = name
     self.factory.users[name] = self
     self.state = "CHAT"

def handle_CHAT(self, message):
     message = "<%s> %s" % (self.name, message)
     self.broadcastMessage(message)

def broadcastMessage(self, message):
     for name, protocol in self.factory.users.iteritems():
        if protocol != self:
           protocol.sendLine(message)
```

what the benefits from `self.x[y]=self`?

Comment: The benefits? The benefit is that the code works I guess :P Without seeing where this instance is used (and how) it would be impossible to give a concrete answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the info, I'll retract my vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.factory.users` is a *shared mapping*; each and every instance of this class can access it. It is a central registry of connection instances, if you will. The connection itself is made responsible for *registering itself*.

By storing references to all the per-user instances in `self.factory.users` you can then send messages to **all users**, in the `broadcastMessage` method:

```
for name, protocol in self.factory.users.iteritems():
    if protocol != self:
        protocol.sendLine(message)
```

This loops over all registered instances, and calls `sendLine()` on each and every *other* connection.

Comment: first , ty for the answer 
it is necessary to write, self.factory.users[name] = self
or its the same thing as, if protocol != self.factory.users[name]:

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to actually assign `self` to a key in that mapping. `if protocol != self.factory.users[name]` can easily throw an exception if `name` is not in the `self.factory.users` mapping already.

Answer (score 0):

The code uses the self-reference in two ways:

1. To determine if a name in the chatroom is already taken
2. To send everyone else a message (i.e. to prevent to send a copy of the message to the user who wrote it).

To achieve #2, they iterate over all items in the `dict` `self.factory.users`. The keys are users in the chatroom. Values are instances of the chat.

When `protocol != self`, then the code has found an instance which doesn't belong to the current user.